# How Facebook push new code in Android App without updating app?

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook is doing continuous app update... how they are pushing live code into app?

Anyone have a idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

It's called remote config. Though you can't do major changes in main functionality or something but still can do few things. Search it, and here is link to firebase's Remote config feature and how to integrate it etc etc. [FireBase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/features/remote-config/)

Comment: thnx bhavesh.. i will check

Answer (score 0):

By performing regular updates through the Google App Store. No rocket science here.